# SignalR proxy is undefined

Tags: javascript, webforms, signalr

why  `$.connection.connectionhub` is undefined, am using webform.

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" "></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {


            $.connection()
            // why it is  undefined
            var chat = $.connection.connectionhub;
```

---------------------------Hub Class------------------------------

```
  public class ConnectionHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }
        public void SendMessage()
        {

        }
    }
```

------------------------Scripts----------------------------------

[image]

Comment: Please post the class declaration for the Hub

Comment: can I create a hub folder, and keep all hubs in that folder?

Comment: Yes, you can put the hubs in any folder

Comment: ok what will be the path when creating a proxy?

Comment: I have test it, if I keep hub in a folder it does not create the proxy?

Comment: same path, it has nothing to do with the folder of the Hub on the backend

Comment: can you share latest tutorial webform using signal r?

Comment: @HaithamShaddad why it is not creating a proxy any guess?

Comment: Can you give the hub a name in the ConnectionHub class and try again? You can add a name with the    ` [HubName("")]` attribute, also you can retrive teh hub in Javascript using another method: `$.connection.createHubProxy('connectionhub')`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, but am not satisfy what is the behavior of this code? any one can elaborate it?

when I write below code it works fine

```
var hubb = $.connection.connectionHub;
```

when I write the code
//only h is small it can't work
var hubb = $.connection.connectionhub;

can any one explain logic here??

snap shot of code

[image]

Comment: @haitham shaddad this is the solution to my problem